# Power Automate > SharePoint list > Update item

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I need to set up a flow that will look up a specific sharepoint list item, take some data from 3 of the items columns and update the corresponding columns on another list.

List A > Static list, contains student information (name, student ID, D.O.B etc.) almost like a directory.
List B > New items added when a MS form is completed

List B has regular updates as the MS form is completed following appointments with students. I need List B to look up some of the data from A and add them to the entry for invoicing purposes. Please note, this only applies to 3 of the total columns, List A has a lot more information for different purposes.

I can't have the MS form users add this themselves for each entry as previous attempts have resulted in data inaccuracies.

I have tried various iterations of flows with the trigger being "when an item is created".

Attempts have including simply using "get items" and "update item" as well as "VAR lookup data" with varying degrees of success and i'm afraid I have hit a wall with it.

Problems encountered include the flow running for all list items rather than the new item, List B having all items update with the same entry and flows running "successfully" with no apparent result reflected in the desired columns.

Any ideas or guidance most welcome.

Please note, I am self-taught but have had great success using automate for various functions, however, have no formal training in it nor a background in coding - hopefully the solution is easy for some folks out there with more skills than I.

What I have tried:

When an item is created > Get items >  Control (name match) > Update item
When an item is created > Get items > VAR look up data (array) > Update item

I expected the item created would have empty columns updated to include information from a source list but this has resulted in a few different consequences including no results, flow run errors, looping flow runs, incorrect entries